# OnActionExecuting Not Getting Executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am troubleshooting a ASP.NET MVC application and on one server the OnActionExecuting is not firing. It has been a long time since I looked at filters. What can keep the OnActionExecuting from running? The effect in our application is the user context never really gets set up (Initialize)... so everything redirects the user back to the login page.

Here is the code of the filter. Note "Jupiter" was the codename of the project

```
public class JupiterAuthenticationFilter :  IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IJupiterContext _jupiterContext;

    public JupiterAuthenticationFilter(IJupiterContext jupiterContext)
    {
        if (jupiterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("jupiterContext");
        }

        _jupiterContext = jupiterContext;
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _jupiterContext.Initialize();
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Is constructor called and the context is not null?

Comment: Authorization filters are always called before other filters, so if the user is not logged on, this wont be called

Comment: Yes, ctor is called and the context is not null but the context's properties are not setup yet. ex. int UserId = 0

Comment: Any idea why this would work on local machine and production machine and NOT on my QA box. Exact same code.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen when your Controller has System.Web.MVC implementation, but ActionFilter has System.Web.Http.